# Getting Hidden Values after $(window).load method in code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

Context:
I converted HTML Select to Multiselect checkboxes on runtime. This required that I write my javascript code on the jquery event :

```
$(window).load(function () {
        mulDC(); //this func converts loaded HTML select to ul with checkboxes

    });
```

Now whatever user selects/checks on the run, I need those values back in my C# code behind.

What I have already tried is, 
I created Hiddenfield and used it to populate it:

```
$('#<%=hdnDC.ClientID %>').val(arrSelectedValues);
```

This is returning me empty since this piece of code is inside .load method. I cannot use document.ready.

Need help here :)

UPDATE:

Function mulDC(). If code for .multiselect (external js file) is important, I can attach that too.

```
 function mulDC() {
        $('#chkDC').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true,
            renderInDiv: '#accDC',
            showSelectedIn: '#selDC',
            showSelectedValueIn: '#selDCVal',
            chkBoxesID: 'chkDC'
        });
        getAllValueDC();
        $('#chkDC li input:checkbox').on('change', function () {
            getAllValueDC()
        });

        function getAllValueDC() {
            var sThisVal = $('#chkDC :checkbox:checked').map(function () {
                return this.value + ',';
            }).get();
          $('#<%=hdnDC.ClientID %>').val(sThisVal);  
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to show code of `mulDC()` which is very important part of question.

Comment: can you show us your rendered HTML for select ?